# Signaling between threads in Python

Tags: python, multithreading, celery

I am working on a realtime data grabber. I have a while True loop, and inside it, I spawn threads that do relatively small tasks (I am querying a 3rd party API over HTTP, and to achieve fast speeds I am querying in parallel).

Every thread takes care of updating a specific data series. This might take 2, 3 or even 5 seconds. However, my while True loop might spawn threads faster than how long it takes for the thread to finish. Hence, I need the spawned threads to wait for their previous threads to finish.

In general, its unpredictable how long it takes for the threads to finish because the threads query an HTTP server...

I was thinking of creating a named semaphore for every thread, and then if a thread spawned for a specific series finds a previous thread working on the same series, it will wait.

The only issue that I can see is a possible backlog of threads..

What is the best solution here? Should I look into things like Celery? I am currently using the threading module.

Thanks!

Comment: If the task is CPU-bound then using threads won't give you performance benefits due to GIL.

Comment: If you have parallel data but no queue then you're doing it wrong. You should have a few workers that take their input (ie one url to download) from one queue and put their result (the downloaded data) into another queue. Other workers can use this queue to process the data further and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another option you could use if you are just requerying the API every time one of your queries returns is an asyncronous framework like Twisted ([Their tutorial on Threading](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/core/howto/threading.html)).  I'm a relative Twisted beginner so there may be better ways of twisting Twisted to your task than this -

```
from twisted.internet import reactor, defer
def simple_task():
    status = query_your_api()
    return status

def repeating_call(status):
    print(status)
    d = threads.deferToThread(simple_task)
    d.addCallback(repeating_call)

data_series = [data1, data2, data3]
for data in data_series:
    repeating_call('starting everything up')

reactor.run()
```

Answer (score 2):

NO!   Please, for the love of your God or intelligent designer, don't do that!  Don't continually create/spawn/whatever threads and try to micro-manage them.  Threadpool - create some threads at startup and pass them a producer-consumer queue to wait on for class instances representing those HTTP tasks.

Answer (score 2):

You should use `Queue.Queue`.  Create a queue for each series, and a thread to listen on that queue.  Each time you need to read a series, put a request in the queue.  The thread waits for items in the queue, and each one it receives, it reads the data.